# Dynamic editor upload into web page. Need advice

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am writing intranet site for tracking employees science activities in organization. 
There lots of editable information on each personal page (science degree, publications & so on) so I upload editor per request (user clicks "edit" and modal dialog with html editor: set of textboxes/comboboxes/autocomplete features & validation logic appears).

Editor is html layout that is wrapped with *jquery dialog* plugin + some logic, written as javascript functions that should be invoked from the callee page (onsubmit, validate, afterLoad editor events). There are also attributes (editor preferrable with and height) that are passed to callee page also.

Currently I send these functions & attribute as ...   function onsubmit() {  };  function validate() {  } var width = 640; var height = 800  ... code that is embedded into the request page. Function calls and editor markup wrap with jquery plugin completed in the callee page.

It works, but I have some try { call editor event handler } catch { } stuff in callee page (because not every editor provides these functions) and some attributes (editor width & height for instance) that are loaded as variables declared in javascript.

Please, suggest, is there a better approach to build & use custom editors for my situation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First off, maybe you can use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). This editor has a jQuery adapter so that you can instantiate the editor very easy:

```
$('#editor1').ckeditor({
                language : 'en',
                toolbar : 'Basic',
                width : 640,
                height : 800
              });
```

You pass all needed informations at the edit page loading to the callee page and load the editor afterwards:
User click edit link -> Ajax request to get the necessary edit infos -> Editor rendering
Perhaps you can write different editor renderers, one for each use case.